# Merge uniq counters, probabilistic data structures

Tags: data-structures, probability, cardinality, hyperloglog

There are two sets `1 2 3` and `3 4` with `3` and `2` unique items.

Now let's calculate unique items in merged set. If we just sum up the counters `3 + 2 = 5` it will be wrong (it should be `uniq(1 2 3 3 4) = 4`).

Is there a way to do it **using only the counters**? For each counter it's ok to use some extra **constant memory** data structure representing the original set, **small errors are also ok**, let's say 95% accuracy is ok.

I know there are probabilistic unique counters using very little memory (HyperLogLog). But is there a way to merge two such probabilistic counters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, HyperLogLog actually allows merging quite naturally, and most implementations include merging. In a nutshell, to merge two HyperLogLog structures A and B into a new one C, take the maximum of each bucket pair C[i] = max(A[i],B[i]).